# Extended supersymmetry and chiral gauge theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, group-theory, supersymmetry

I'm trying to understand the argument that extended supersymmetry cannot produce the chiral structure of the Standard Model, as explained on page 25 of [these notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/examples/3P7.pdf). My impression of the argument goes like this:

- All particles in a supermultiplet must transform the same way under internal symmetries.
- All massless particles with helicity $|\lambda| = 1$ must be created by gauge fields, because gauge symmetry is the only way to get rid of the extra degrees of freedom.
- Gauge fields must transform under the adjoint representation of any gauge group, and for all matrix Lie groups the adjoint representation is real.
- In extended SUSY, with one exception, all multiplets containing $|\lambda| = 1/2$ also contain $|\lambda| = 1$. Thus we can only get fermions in real representations of any gauge group.
- This is incompatible with the chiral structure of the Standard Model, which requires that fermions live in complex representations, such as left-handed quarks, which are in the doublet representation of $SU(2)_L$.

Granted that I paraphrased the argument correctly, I'm fine with every step except for the last step, which just doesn't seem right to me.

---

Here are the preliminary thoughts I've had about this:

- It's ambiguous whether we're talking about the representations of fields or representations of particles. These are different but I haven't been able to make the argument work either way.
- It's ambiguous whether 'complex' means $\text{complex}_1$, i.e. the base field is the complex numbers, or $\text{complex}_2$, i.e. the representation is $\text{complex}_1$ and not equivalent to its conjugate. I think the only sensible option is $\text{complex}_2$.
- The doublet representation of $SU(2)_L$ is *not* $\text{complex}_2$! There is only one two-dimensional representation of $SU(2)_L$ so it must necessarily be equivalent to its conjugate.
- In [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/178658/why-do-we-need-complex-representations-in-grand-unified-theories) it is argued that if $q_L$ transforms in a representation $R$, then $q_R$ transforms in the conjugate representation $\bar{R}$. Therefore if $R$ is real, $q_L$ and $q_R$ transform the same way, which contradicts observation. But this seems clearly wrong, it's not true for $q_L$ and $q_R$ in the Standard Model!

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: Might specify by "internal symmetry" you mean one commuting with the extended SUSY algebra, whose global bosonic symmetries you are ignoring here...

Comment: Note that the $SU(2)$ doublet is pseudoreal (quaternionic), not real.

Comment: @RyanThorngren Yes, but I think the common usage of "complex" is "not real or pseudoreal".

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes, that's what I mean here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You must be talking about the representations of the *fields*, since the particles are quantum states that always live in infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space with corresponding *unitary* representations on it.
2. Let us make clear what we really mean by "chirality" of the Standard Model. Given a Dirac fermion $\psi$ with its chiral parts/Weyl fermions $\psi_L,\psi_R$, chirality means that $\psi_L$ transforms under a different representation of at least one gauge group (the weak one in the case of the SM) than $\psi_R$. For how exactly this translates to our ordinary natural language of left/right-handed electrons and positron, see [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/246746/50583) to a previous question of yours.
3. The meaning of "complex" here is "not real", not "complex" as in "not real or pseudoreal". For the difference between real, pseudoreal and complex, see [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/380810/50583) to another previous question of yours.
4. When we say that "a Weyl spinor" $\psi_{R/L}$ transforms in the representation $\rho$ of a gauge group, what we really formally would have to say that the object transforms in the combined representation $(1/2,0)\otimes \rho$ where $(1/2,0)$ is the usual notation for the Weyl spinor representation of the Lorentz group.
5. Finally, we are in a position to observe the following: Given a massless multiplet with a Weyl fermion of any handedness in it and a real representation of the gauge group, we can *split the result of the tensor product* since we can split the real representation $\rho$ into two representations on real vector spaces as $\rho_\mathbb{R} + J\rho_\mathbb{R}$, where $J$ is basically a complex conjugation map:
   $$ (1/2,0) \otimes \rho = \left( (1/2,0) \otimes \rho_\mathbb{R} \right) \oplus \left( (1/2,0) \otimes J\rho_\mathbb{R}\right)$$

All that is left to do is to observe that $(1/2,0)\otimes J\rho_\mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to $J(1/2,0)\otimes \rho_\mathbb{R}$, and that $J(1/2,0) = (0,1/2)$ - the conjugate representation of a left-handed Weyl fermion is a right-handed Weyl fermion. Therefore, choosing a real representation $\rho$ of the gauge group for a Weyl fermion actually results in the Weyl fermion transforming in $\rho_\mathbb{R}$ and its opposite-chirality version also transforming in $\rho_\mathbb{R}$, explaining why real representations can never lead to chirally symmetric theories.

Observe also that this argument *fails* for a pseudoreal representation, which also resolves the apparent contradiction with the doublet of $\mathrm{SU}(2)_L$ being "not complex".

Comment: I agree with everything you said in the first few points. Over the years I've asked several questions about charge conjugation, chirality, and helicity, and I have to thank you for patiently teaching me the essential points. (I think I finally have a full understanding, written up [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/178658/why-do-we-need-complex-representations-in-grand-unified-theories/403960#403960).)

Comment: However, I think we're working from different definitions of what a "chiral gauge theory" is. I agree with your reasoning given your definition, but consider the particles in a theory with just a left-chiral Weyl field transforming in an $SU(2)$ doublet. We have four, corresponding to helicity $\pm 1/2$, and "$I_3$" value $\pm 1/2$. Everything is perfectly symmetric under the charge conjugation operator $\hat{C}$, as well as $\hat{P}$. I would expect a "chiral gauge theory" to not be $\hat{C}$ and $\hat{P}$ symmetric.

Comment: To summarize, I think you define a chiral gauge theory so that a non-chiral gauge theory is one where you can pair up left-chiral and right-chiral Weyl spinors in real representations. But I instead define a chiral gauge theory to be one that violates $\hat{C}$ and $\hat{P}$; then a pseudoreal representation can't be chiral. Papers on this seem to just say a chiral gauge theory has a complex representation, but we already know this word is ambiguous. Do you have a definitive reference here?

Comment: @knzhou: FWIW, [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(physics)#Chiral_symmetry) agrees with mine. I'll see if I can find better references, but it might take a while.

Comment: No worries, it's just a semantics issue! In any case the full SM fermion representation is not pseudoreal, so either definition works fine there.